# BootStrap with many Controls halts on Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I'm trying to optimize a page which is also served for mobile using Twitter-BootStrap. The page has over one thousand `<button>` elements. It also has jQuery which binds each button to the On click.

Problem: On mobile Iphone Safari scrolling the page is not smooth and it halts regularly.

Are there any possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: How is the event binding done?

Comment: element.class then looping each() wrapped function { bind click

Comment: Binding the events inside an each loop can be slow and unnecessary. Instead of `$('selector').each(function() { $(this).on('event', callback) ...` it should be done directly `$('selector').on('event', callback);`